# How to open colorbox after validation failed : Gravity Forms

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, colorbox, gravity-forms-plugin

I am having a situation, where i used colorbox to display the gravity forms. When user fills in details, the gravity form goes to its confirmation page and the colorbox closes due to new page loaded. So i want to show the colorbox as opened if user submits the wrong information.

Here is the URL to see it in action, after login go to the given URL :-

```
http://dev.guestseed.com/trip-hub-main-page/basics/
username : mytestuser
password : mytestuser
```

After submitting the General Info,the colorbox closes even if there are errors submitting the form. Like if we input wrong email address and website url, form closes and if we again try to add then from is showing errors.

I want to show the popup as opened if validations fails. Any help will be appericiated. I wasted 4 days on this issue only. Also tried client side validations, but no luck.

Comment: Please atleast let me know if there is problem with question

Comment: i am a little girl troubling here, no people can help me who are having many reputations ? :( :(